# Getting 400 bad request Error from apache Http client in Zuul gateway and request is not reaching to downstream service

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have Zuul gateway in my service which gets the request from UI and forward it to Downstream service. I am not using ribbon and using the simple routing filter of Zuul.
my application YAML file is:

```
zuul:
debug:
    request: true
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000 # starting the connection
    socket-timeout-millis: 600000  # monitor the continuous incoming data flow
  add-proxy-headers: true
  routes:
    service:
      path: /service/**
      sensitive-headers:
      url: <service-url>
```

It is working as expected but I am facing an intermittent issue where for some request I am getting 400 bad request error and the request is not even reaching to the downstream routed service.

I enabled the debug logs and saw in the logs of apache wire that whenever I get the 400 response there is an additional string added in the headers(I guess):
Please see the logs:

```
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-forwarded-host:  <HOST>
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-forwarded-server: <SERVER>
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-forwarded-proto: https,http
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-envoy-external-address: <EXTERNAL ADDRESS>
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-request-id: <REQUEST ID>[
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms: 1200000
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-request-start: t=1589262419.335
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> x-forwarded-prefix: /api/service
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> Host: <HOST>
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "pZCI6IkEwMkY0MjM4MUYxMjAzMTBFMDUzMTJFQjQyQTkxMjM2IiwiZW1haWwiOiJhYmhpc2hla21pc2hyYTIwMzdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJNaXNocmEiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlhyOVIxUHdxeWciLCJleHAiOjE1ODkyOTA0OTl9.N1wC0ChcHwTncwcePPGq_xcwBrXbr9Igb3XaxkFKbFPv8JjhWoX68ZqT8LSUp7OU8SfPsiP4BVLIqF6hgAKkWZVWVCKc7oJ0I796qVXZUFNkUHq8GLFCdunQ1thLkqdLJ6YeIt0WoQmlfKTJe14krD8p0Ue9gheR0fvqdKIeSIY[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "x-forwarded-prefix: /api/service[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "Host: <HOST>[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.367 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.367 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 << "[\r][\n]"
05:46:59.367 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-494 << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

05:46:59.366 default [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-494 >> "***pZCI6IkEwMkY0MjM4MUYxMjAzMTBFMDUzMTJFQjQyQTkxMjM2IiwiZW1haWwiOiJhYmhpc2hla21pc2hyYTIwMzdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJNaXNocmEiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlhyOVIxUHdxeWciLCJleHAiOjE1ODkyOTA0OTl9.N1wC0ChcHwTncwcePPGq_xcwBrXbr9Igb3XaxkFKbFPv8JjhWoX68ZqT8LSUp7OU8SfPsiP4BVLIqF6hgAKkWZVWVCKc7oJ0I796qVXZUFNkUHq8GLFCdunQ1thLkqdLJ6YeIt0WoQmlfKTJe14krD8p0Ue9gheR0fvqdKIeSIY***[\r][\n]"

this the additional string I am talking about and not sure why is getting added here and also I am not adding anything in the original request headers other than my own two additional headers
which is required by the downstream service.

Also if you see the logs for the Success scenario logs, this additional string is not present there:

```
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-forwarded-host: <HOST>[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-forwarded-server: <SERVER>[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-forwarded-proto: https,http[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-envoy-external-address: <EXTERNAL ADDRESS>[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-request-id: <REQUEST ID>[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms: 1200000[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-request-start: t=1589273901.838[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "x-forwarded-prefix: /api/service[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "Host: <HOST>[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
08:58:21.865 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 >> "[\r][\n]"
08:58:22.352 default [SimpleHostRoutingFilter.connectionManagerTimer] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
08:58:23.989 default [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-553 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
```

This is very intermittent issue and I am unable to find what is the root cause for this error.
And also in case of 400 error request is not even reaching to the downstream service.

Also in both the cases same API call was made (GET CALL).

Please help me with this, I am unable to figure it out why it is happening.

Comment: Researching something similar myself, not resolved yet. But here's some things I"m looking at.


***AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient*** is catching ALL exceptions and re-throwing them as ClientException's. I believe this is the root of the bug.



ClientException includes things like number of retries exceeded, and read_timeout_exception.so it may already be a 400 when I wouldn't classify it as that myself.





RibbonHttpRequest calls executeWithLoadBalancer() which will throw the above exception.




DefaultResponseErrorHandler or RibbonRoutingFilter might also be in play.

Comment: By any chance did you resolve this issue ? I am also facing the same